# Where are config folder and bin folder of Neo4j Desktop on iMac?

Tags: neo4j

It is simple to find out the Neo4j community version's config and bin folders. They are in the folders I installed Neo4j community version.

But for Neo4j Desktop, I cannot find the bin and config folders.

Neo4j Desktop App

```
/Applications/Neo4j Desktop
```

Neo4j Desktop App databases

```
~/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases
```

But I cannot find where the Neo4j Desktop config and bin folders are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open the `Neo4j Desktop`.
2. In the `Projects` panel on the left, click on a project.
3. Click on the `Manage` button for the project.
4. Click on the `Open Folder` button (not the down-arrow to its right).
5. A Finder window will pop up, displaying the contents of the installation folder for that project, including the the `conf` and `bin` folders.

Comment: thank you @cybersam .. difficult to find it and the locations. When installing, it was not required where to set the folder up, and so I was checking on /Sites/ folders ... very cumbersome